# "Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process" on a completely empty app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm just trying to learn how to use Firebase, so I've created a completely empty app and wanted to set a base to start trying stuff, but I am getting this error.

I've implemented Firebase using the assistant and only put in the two lines of code the intro guide in Firebase is instruting to input. No idea what I can change as I've literally put nothing inside.

this is the line that's causing the crash

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
```

Any ideas?

I've looked at other threads where people have asked this question but it seems that their code had much more that could have been changed, or what the answers have instructed was already tru for my case.

This is my mainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)

        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val myRef = database.getReference("message")


    }
}
```

That's my app Gradle build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.getdere.firebaseexperiments"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And this is the project Gradle Build file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Have you added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` as the last line in your gradle file?

Comment: the google service plugin must be applied at the very bottom of the gradle file

Comment: @AlexMamo yes it did it automatically at the top

Comment: @TimCastelijns you're talking about this line correct? `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
The assistant placed it there automatically, but anyway I've moved it to the bottom and it still crashes.

Comment: @Tsabary Pleas also add the content of the other build.gradle (Project) file.

Comment: @AlexMamo added.

Comment: do you have a google-services.json file in the root folder of the project? I assume the assistant created it but just making sure

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes I do. Looks like the problem is solved after Faysal's advice to update the service version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update google service version to `4.2.0`.

Use this

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Instead of

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Comment: Looks like it did.. Thanks for noticing that Faysal!

Comment: @TimCastelijns For recent update of Android Studio to `3.3.1` that have a problem with `com.google.gms:google-services (Below 4.2.0)`. That's why `FirebaseApp`  not initialized properly.